# ArrayList initialization equivalent to array initialization

Tags: java, arrays, initialization, arraylist

I am aware that you can initialize an array during instantiation as follows:

```
String[] names = new String[] {"Ryan", "Julie", "Bob"};
```

Is there a way to do the same thing with an ArrayList? Or must I add the contents individually with `array.add()`?

Answer (score 390, accepted):

[Arrays.asList](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29) can help here:

```
new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1,2,3,5,8,13,21));
```

Comment: It's worth mentioning that unless you strictly need an `ArrayList` it's probably better to just use the `List` that's returned by `Arrays#asList`.

Comment: @maerics, it's also worth mentioning that `Arrays.asList()` return an **unmodifiable** collection. :)

Comment: It will throw compilation error "The method asList(Object[]) in the type Arrays is not applicable for the arguments (int, int, int, int, int, int, int)"..

Comment: Actual implementation should be "new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(new Object[]{1,2,3,5,8,13,21}));"

Comment: @RK: With which compiler? My eclipse compiles it just fine ...

Comment: @meriton: I have set the compiler level and JRE pointed to 1.5...

Comment: @RK: On my eclipse, it still compiles with Java 5 compliance against a JRE 6. Seing that the method signature hasn't changed since JRE 5, I doubt the JRE matters. And anyway, Java 5 had been end of live by the time I wrote this answer. (you aren't really still using it, are you?)

Comment: The list returned by `Arrays.asList()` is _NOT_ unmodifiable, @kocko.  It has a fixed size, but you can change the references to point to entirely different objects like `Arrays.asList(...).set(0,new String("new string"))`  This code will work and set the first element of the list to the String object with value "new string".  And in fact, it writes through to the native array!  Definitely _not_ unmodifiable.

Comment: Why do people never mention correct import/include/require statement in their posts?

Comment: Because a well configured IDE will write the imports for you, as long as there is a single matching class, as is the case here.

Comment: @KonstantinYovkov ...which is entirely within the contract of a List object

Comment: Works perfectly!

Comment: @meriton For many uses, there might be multiple matching classes (e.g. there is a List in awt). Many third party libraries provide their own similarly called Classes. So it is clearer and unambiguous to mention it, and also just more convenient to have them listed in the answer.

Comment: @xuiqzy: The ArrayList class we are talking about here is already mentioned in the question (without imports! And I still understood what he was talking about ...). And the Arrays class is mentioned with a link to the Javadoc, which contains the fully qualified class name, and also reveals that the class is part of the JDK in case there was any doubt. I therefore don't think the missing import creates any ambiguity here. If you feel that imports should be written as a matter of policy, please discuss this over on meta.

Comment: You are right that it is unambiguous, but it requires extra effort from every reader who wants to know by following the link or seeing if it's mentioned in the question again (it is common and useful to skim the question and see if a solution answers one's problem) and makes copy pasting to test a potential solution harder.

Answer (score 64):

Yes.

```
new ArrayList<String>(){{
   add("A");
   add("B");
}}
```

What this is actually doing is creating a class derived from `ArrayList<String>` (the outer set of braces do this) and then declare a static initialiser (the inner set of braces). This is actually an *inner* class of the containing class, and so it'll have an implicit `this` pointer. Not a problem unless you want to serialise it, or you're expecting the outer class to be garbage collected.

I understand that Java 7 will provide [additional language constructs](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/coin-dev/2009-March/001193.html) to do precisely what you want.

EDIT: recent Java versions provide more usable functions for creating such collections, and are worth investigating over the above (provided at a time prior to these versions)

Comment: Probably because people don't know this is possible. This is actually my favorite way to initialize maps and other more complex collections but for lists, i prefer Arrays.asList.

Comment: Not my downvote, but I consider this a pretty nasty abuse of anonymous classes. At least you're not trying to pass it off as a special feature...

Comment: Bad because it creates an anonymous class.

Comment: I don't believe that creating an anonymous class is bad *in itself*. You should be aware of it though.

Comment: I'm guessing that it keeps getting downvoted because it does just what the OP wanted to avoid: using add() for each element.

Comment: Be careful, the solution can cause memory leak

Comment: I would consider downvoting, because *creating a class*, just to initialize a single object, strikes me as overkill. But I'm not sufficiently an expert in java to know whether this is a bad thing to do. Maybe creating thousands of unnecessary classes, in a large program, is considered good java coding? Its also horrendously verbose, if there are many elements. Is there *any advantage* to this approach, versus other proposed answers?

Comment: It might have been downvoted because it only works for final values.  I agree your solution does work for what the question asked, but you know some people are on StackOverflow.

Comment: It's probably being downvoted because, in all likelihood, the majority of the users who will use this solution will not read/understand the explanation. It's *crucial* that anyone who uses this really, fully understands what they are doing and how it works.

Comment: While this looks nice it's a very bad idea, this will generate unnecessary class objects that will immediately need to be garbage collected.  Having this in your code is inviting difficult to diagnose future memory problems just for a little syntactic sugar.

Comment: Whilst there are known downsides to such initialisation, I would question your assertion re. memory problems, particularly given the notes above and the limited scenario presented

Comment: Looks like @BrianAgnew discusses this further in [another SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1958961/1265245). 

Comment: It's not a "static initialiser" , it's an "instance initialization block"

Answer (score 40):

Here is the closest you can get:

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList("Ryan", "Julie", "Bob"));
```

You can go even simpler with:

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("Ryan", "Julie", "Bob")
```

Looking at the source for Arrays.asList, it constructs an ArrayList, but by default is cast to List.  So you could do this (but not reliably for new JDKs):

```
ArrayList<String> list = (ArrayList<String>)Arrays.asList("Ryan", "Julie", "Bob")
```

Comment: The ArrayList constructed by asList is not a java.util.ArrayList, only shares the same. In fact, it cannot be, as the return value of asList is specified to be a fixed size list, but an ArrayList must be of variable size.

Comment: I stand corrected.  I did not read far enough into the source.

Answer (score 32):

```
Arrays.asList("Ryan", "Julie", "Bob");
```

Comment: Important: This initializes a fixed size `List`, but not a variable size `ArrayList`!

Comment: The Javadocs make no mention that this returns an ArrayList.

Answer (score 9):

Well, in Java there's no literal syntax for lists, so you have to do .add().

If you have a lot of elements, it's a bit verbose, but you could either:

1. use Groovy or something like that
2. use Arrays.asList(array)

2 would look something like:

```
String[] elements = new String[] {"Ryan", "Julie", "Bob"};
List list = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(elements));
```

This results in some unnecessary object creation though.

Answer (score 6):

The selected answer is: `ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1,2,3,5,8,13,21));`

However, its important to understand the selected answer internally copies the elements several times before creating the final array, and that there is a way to reduce some of that redundancy.

Lets start by understanding what is going on:

1. First, the elements are copied into the `Arrays.ArrayList<T>` created by the static factory `Arrays.asList(T...)`.

   This does not the produce the same class as `java.lang.ArrayList`despite having the same simple class name.  It does not implement methods like `remove(int)` despite having a List interface. If you call those methods it will throw an `UnspportedMethodException`. But if all you need is a fixed-sized list, you can stop here.
2. Next the `Arrays.ArrayList<T>` constructed in #1  gets passed to the constructor `ArrayList<>(Collection<T>)` where the `collection.toArray()` method is called to clone it.

   ```
   public ArrayList(Collection<? extends E> collection) {
   ......
   Object[] a = collection.toArray();
   }
   ```
3. Next the constructor decides whether to adopt the cloned array, or copy it again to remove the subclass type.  Since `Arrays.asList(T...)` internally uses an array of type T, the very same one we passed as the parameter, the constructor always rejects using the clone unless T is a pure Object. (E.g. String, Integer, etc all get copied again, because they extend Object).

   ```
   if (a.getClass() != Object[].class) {      
       //Arrays.asList(T...) is always true here 
       //when T subclasses object
       Object[] newArray = new Object[a.length];
       System.arraycopy(a, 0, newArray, 0, a.length);
       a = newArray;
   }
   array = a;
   size = a.length;
   ```

Thus, our data was copied 3x just to explicitly initialize the ArrayList.  We could get it down to 2x if we force `Arrays.AsList(T...)` to construct an Object[] array, so that ArrayList can later adopt it, which can be done as follows:

```
(List<Integer>)(List<?>) new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList((Object) 1, 2 ,3, 4, 5));
```

Or maybe just adding the elements after creation might still be the most efficient.

Answer (score 5):

How about this one.

```
ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
Collections.addAll(names, "Ryan", "Julie", "Bob");
```

Answer (score 2):

This is how it is done using the fluent interface of the [op4j](http://www.op4j.org) Java library (1.1. was released Dec '10) :-

```
List<String> names = Op.onListFor("Ryan", "Julie", "Bob").get();
```

It's a very cool library that saves you a tonne of time.