# Java quick array list

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have a very simple question:

How can I make this code more simple on Java:

```
ArrayList<String> s = new ArrayList<String>();
s.add("str1");
s.add("str hello");
s.add("str bye");
//...
```

Something like that:

```
ArrayList<String> s = {"a1", "str", "mystr"};
```

or that:

```
ArrayList<String> s = new ArrayList<String>("a1", "str", "mystr");
```

or that:

```
ArrayList<String> s = new ArrayList<String>();
s.addAll("a1", "str", "mystr");
```

or that:

```
ArrayList<String> s = new ArrayList<String>();
s.addAll(new ArrayElements("a1", "str", "mystr"));
```

I just want syntax hint. Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2760995/java-arraylist-initialization

Answer (score 25, accepted):

How about:

```
ArrayList<String> s = new ArrayList<String>();
Collections.addAll(s, "a1", "str", "mystr");
```

Answer (score 41):

`List<String> s = Arrays.asList("a1", "str", "mystr");`

Comment: This returns a fixed-size list not a java.util.ArrayList. So it is good when no more adding or removing of elements is needed.

Comment: This is true. It wasn't clear from the OP whether this would be an issue or not.

Answer (score 5):

```
List<String> s = Arrays.asList(new String[] {"a1", "str", "mystr"});
```

Comment: @Rob: the OP asks for simple, not for fast

Comment: `List<String> s = Arrays.asList("a1", "str", "mystr");` is even better

Answer (score 5):

I would use [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) and its wonderful [`Lists`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v10.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html) class:

```
List<String> list = Lists.newArrayList("a1", "str", "mystr");
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use double brace:

```
ArrayList<String> s = new ArrayList<String>()
{{
    add("str1");
    add("str hello");
    add("str bye");
    //...
}};
```

Comment: Rather than just producing esoteric syntax, wouldn't it be a good idea to explain to the OP what that is and how it works?

Comment: dty, it is double brace initialization, it explained in http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DoubleBraceInitialization in detail.

Comment: There are reasons why you might not want to do this.  This essentially creates a new anonymous inner class definition every time it's run, which can have side effects on a long running app, or if you execute this snippet frequently.  It's often better to not use this form of initialization, because even if you understand the implications, someone on your team who may copy you may not.  There are safer ways to do this

Answer (score 2):

Before or after Java 8 you can write:

```
ArrayList<String> s = 
    new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("str1", "str hello", "str bye"));
```

Since Java 8 you can write:

```
ArrayList<String> s =
    Stream.of("str1", "str hello", "str bye")
        .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```

With [Eclipse Collections](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse-collections) you can write the following:

```
ArrayList<String> s =
    Lists.mutable.with("str1", "str hello", "str bye")
        .into(new ArrayList<>());
```

If you can use `List` instead of `ArrayList`:

```
List<String> s = Lists.mutable.with("str1", "str hello", "str bye");
```

Note: I am a committer for Eclipse Collections.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Java 9, you could use [List.of()](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/util/List.html#of-E...-) :

```
List<String> s = List.of("str1", "str hello", "str bye");
```

But this would be an immutable list. If you need a mutable Arraylist:

```
ArrayList<String> s = new ArrayList<>(List.of("str1", "str hello", "str bye"))
```