# adding objects to a ArrayList<String>

Tags: android

I believe you can add objects use list.add(); However, is there an alternative way of making an ArrayList of strings? Something like ArrayList("heyey","hgfhgfh","fhfghgf") ?

Comment: Check out [this SO question][1] about initializing ArrayList in Java.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2760995/java-arraylist-initialization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("ohai", "I", "have", "varargs");
```

Or if you're kickin' it old school:

```
List strings = new ArrayList() {{
    add("ohai");
    add("Java 1.4");
    add("lives");
}};
```

Answer (score 2):

```
List<String> listString = Arrays.asList(new String[] {"heyey","hgfhgfh","fhfghgf"});
```

With listString being a fixed size list (see [Arrays.asList](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29)).

If you need a variable size list:

```
List<String> listString = new ArrayList<String<(Arrays.asList(new String[] {"heyey","hgfhgfh","fhfghgf"}));
```