# Arraylist and arrays in Java

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to do some basic stuff with java. I know how to do arrays, but not ArrayList.

" Write a single Java statement that declares and initializes an ArrayList of integers named values"

For a simple array I used  `int [] values ;`

so far I have come up with this, but Im not sure if its correct.

```
new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(values));
```

Comment: What are you asking?  Have you tried writing that in a class and compiling, then run it?  Does it do what you expect?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2760995/arraylist-initialization-equivalent-to-array-initialization

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you would initialize an ArrayList of Integers named values:

```
List<Integer> values = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

ArrayList implements the `List` inteface and extends `AbstractList`.

> Array lists are created with an initial size. When this size is exceeded, the collection is automatically enlarged. When objects are removed, the array may be shrunk.

I would recommend going through a [tutorial](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/05/example-of-arraylist-in-java-tutorial.html) on ArrayLists as they are frequently used in the real world and you should know some of the methods that accompany the ArrayList class.

[Source](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_arraylist_class.htm)

Comment: I think you forgot > after the first Integer.  Thank You for Helping.

Answer (score 0):

Almost right. But `Arrays.asList()` *returns* an `ArrayList`, so all you have to do is declare an `ArrayList<Integer>` and assign the result of the method call to it.

Comment: No, `asList` returns a List which is actually an `Arrays.ArrayList`. This is a private class which is not the same thing as a `java.util.ArrayList`.

Comment: Ah, well. That's what I get for not looking up the documentation before I answer questions. I should probably delete this answer.

Answer (score 0):

It should work

```
ArrayList<Integer> f = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(values));
```

I use eclipse as an editor.

Comment: Your code compiles but it's wrong. The OP has an `int[]`. This only compiles because you have a raw type and you will get a ClassCastException if you try to get anything from the list.